# What are default respond_to formats for Ruby On Rails and how to go about adding new ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-type, feed

So here is what I have:

```
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @profiles }
      format.json  { render :json => @profiles }
    end
  end
```

I would like to add rss, atom and possibly some custom ones such as one that returns the image for the profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register new ones like this (place this in your config/environment.rb, one of the config/environments/*.rb files or in a file under config/initializers):

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.ms-excel', :xls
```

As for the default ones:

```
>> Mime::SET.map(&:to_sym)
=> [:all, :text, :html, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :xls]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the resource_feeder built into rails to do this:

```
script/plugin install simply_helpful
script/plugin install resource_feeder
```

In the profile controller:

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.all

  options = { :feed => { :title => "All Profiles" },
                    :item => { :title => :name } }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render :xml => @profiles
    format.json { render :json => @profiles
    format.rss { render_rss_feed_for @profiles, options }
    format.atom { render_atom_feed_for @profiles, options }
  end
```

end